# React native passing multiple styles from parent to child, which method is more used? what is the difference?

Tags: react-native, parent-child, prop

React native passing multiple styles from parent to child, component, which method is more used? What is the difference?

Rest parameter type,
<Text style={{...styles.title, ...props.style}}>{props.children}

I also found this syntax here:

using array,
<Text style={[styles.title, props.style]}>{props.children}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no differences between the two examples. However, the second way is the standard way to combine styles as mentioned in the `react-native` documentation.

> The `style` prop can be a plain old JavaScript object. That's what we usually use for example code. You can also pass an array of styles - the last style in the array has precedence, so you can use this to inherit styles.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also, see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.